# Eclipse 4 RCP Application "Create Sample Content" and "Enable Development Mode For Application Model" not shown

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Sorry for the long winded title but I'm following Lars Vogels Eclipse 4 RCP tutorials to try and learn Eclipse RCP but am coming across a problem. In step 4.2 of [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) tutorial I'm meant to get a screen like this:

[image]

but all I'm getting is a screen like this:

[image]

Someone asked the same question on [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vogella/eqtQA_GfhLI) but all Lars said to do was to get the latest e4 tools from the [section 3.3 of the original guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) which I have already done.

Am I missing something obvious??

Any advice would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can update like
Help > check for updates

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Download the files from http://vogella.com/updatesite/e4tools instead.

Your screen shot is from the latest from eclipse.org. I had the same issue.

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden Error "You do not have permission to access this document." Strange?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Seams due to e4 Project version 0.12 (which I started from, don't know if that was also the case for earlier versions). I had downloaded it from http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12 update site.
This gave me e4 Tools (Eclipse e4 Modeltooling) version 0.12.0.v20120529-2033

The e4 Project has now released build **0.13**, so I changed my Software Site to :
http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.13
and made an update, obtaining the 0.12.0.v20130221-1605 version for e4 Tools.

It now works (for me ...) as the Lars Vogel tutorial shows (with sample part code) !

Comment: Well, this version is only lacking key binding (Shift+Alt+F9) to display the "live application model" view but you can find it using the "quick access" field ...